# Effect of external charge on the charge distribution of a conductor's inner surface

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Suppose we have a neutral spherical conductor with a spherical "cavity" within. And at the center of the cavity is charge +q. In the absence of any external charge, the surface charge density of the inner wall due to the induced charge, $\sigma$$_{in}$ should be uniform (by virtue of symmetry) and so should be $\sigma$$_{out}$, the surface charge density of the outer surface.

Now, if we brought an external charge +q' near the conductor, how would it affect the two charge densities? It seems clear that $\sigma$$_{out}$ would no longer be uniform, but what about $\sigma$$_{in}$?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming $=q'$ is a point charge...) Since $+q'$ is not at the centre of the cavity, which is the centre of the sphere, I see no reason why the charge distributions would remain spherically symmetric.